# AMD graphics card: What drivers should I install

Tags: drivers, ati, games, steam

I have just downloaded Ubuntu and I am trying to play some Steam games but Steam says that I should update my drivers.

I am using the post release driver, but should I also install the experimental and xorg and kernel module drivers?

Answer (score 0):

For AMD graphics card, there is a `fglrx` closed source driver developped by AMD and there is an open source `radeon` driver developped by the community and AMD but the fact that AMD is helping is new so this driver isn't yet as good as the closed source one.

To install it, follow the instructions [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Valve#Driver_Upgrades).

The driver you will have to uninstall will be `xserver-xorg-video-radeon` or `xserver-xorg-video-ati`